# Lua - How to compensate for strange 2D raycaster engine warping effect (Not fisheye effect)

Tags: lua, love2d

Basicaly I have wrote some code in lua:

```
function love.keypressed( key )
   if key == "f11" then
     fullscreen = not fullscreen
   end
end
pPosX,pPosY = 1,8
pRot,pFOV,pViewRange = -90,95,15
lines = {{0,0,10,0},{10,0,10,10},{0,10,3,10},{7,10,10,10},{3,10,5,8},{5,8,7,10},{0,10,0,0},{2,2,2,8},{8,2,6,4},{2,5,4,5},{6,4,8,4}}

function love.conf(t)
    t.console = true
end

function love.load()
    fullscreen = true
    love.window.setTitle("Raycaster")
    love.window.setMode(1280,720,{})
    love.window.setFullscreen(true, "desktop")
    ScreenX,ScreenY = love.graphics.getDimensions()
end

function love.update(dt)
  love.window.setFullscreen(fullscreen, "desktop")
  if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
    pPosX,pPosY = math.cos(math.rad(pRot))*dt*3+pPosX,math.sin(math.rad(pRot))*dt*3+pPosY
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
    pPosX,pPosY = math.cos(math.rad(pRot))*dt*-3+pPosX,math.sin(math.rad(pRot))*dt*-3+pPosY
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
    pRot = pRot - dt*250
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
    pRot = pRot + dt*250
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
    pPosX,pPosY = math.cos(math.rad(pRot-90))*dt*3+pPosX,math.sin(math.rad(pRot-90))*dt*3+pPosY
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
    pPosX,pPosY = math.cos(math.rad(pRot+90))*dt*3+pPosX,math.sin(math.rad(pRot+90))*dt*3+pPosY
  end
  fps = 1/dt
end
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(0.5, 0.55, 1)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",0,0,ScreenX,ScreenY/2)
    love.graphics.setColor(0.35, 0.3, 0.3)
    love.graphics.rectangle("fill",0,ScreenY/2,ScreenX,ScreenY/2)
    ScreenX,ScreenY = love.graphics.getDimensions()
    for i = 1,ScreenX,1 do
       local scanX = pRot+(i-1)*pFOV/ScreenX-pFOV/2
       local lx1,ly1 = math.cos(math.rad(scanX))*pViewRange+pPosX,math.sin(math.rad(scanX))*pViewRange+pPosY
       local closest = 999999
       for lns = 1,#lines,1 do
          local x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4 = pPosX,pPosY,lx1,ly1,lines[lns][1],lines[lns][2],lines[lns][3],lines[lns][4]
          t,u = ((x1-x3)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y3)*(x3-x4))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4)),
          ((x1-x3)*(y1-y2)-(y1-y3)*(x1-x2))/((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)-(y1-y2)*(x3-x4))
          if t >= 0 and t <= 1 and u >= 0 and u <= 1 then
            x,y = x1+t*(x2-x1),y1+t*(y2-y1)
            Dist = math.sqrt((x - pPosX) ^ 2 + (y - pPosY) ^ 2)*math.cos(math.rad(pRot)-math.rad(scanX))
          else
            Dist = 999999
          end
          if Dist < closest then
            closest = Dist
            mmX,mmY = x,y
          end
       end
      love.graphics.setColor(1.2-closest/pViewRange, 1.2-closest/pViewRange, 0)
      love.graphics.line(pPosX*ScreenX/50,pPosY*ScreenX/50,mmX*ScreenX/50,mmY*ScreenX/50)
      if closest <= pViewRange then
        love.graphics.setColor(1.2-closest/pViewRange, 1.2-closest/pViewRange, 1.2-closest/pViewRange)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill",i,(ScreenY-(ScreenY*(pViewRange-closest)/pViewRange))/2,1,ScreenY*(pViewRange-closest)/pViewRange)
      end
    end
    love.graphics.setColor(1,0,0)
    for lns = 1,#lines,1 do
      love.graphics.line(lines[lns][1]*ScreenX/50,lines[lns][2]*ScreenX/50,lines[lns][3]*ScreenX/50,lines[lns][4]*ScreenX/50)
    end
    love.graphics.setColor(1,1,1)
    love.graphics.print(math.floor(fps+0.5),0.975*ScreenX,0)
end
```

pPosX,PposY are the players coordinates
pRot,pFov,pViewRange are the players rotation in degrees, field of view in degrees, and view range,
lines = {} contains the map which is split up into lines {x1,y1,x2,y2},
the engine checks what resolution the screen is and starts a for i loop that starts the scanX variable at -pFov/2 and increases it by pFov/ScreenX until it reaches pFov/2, the line segment intersection equations are coppied from wikipedia, I have already compensated for the fisheye effect by multiplying Dist (distance from player to intersection) by the cosine of the players angle minus scanX ,but there still is a very strong warping effect:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztUN0.png
As you can see from the minimap the player is looking down a straight hallway, but it looks as if the front is curving away.

Comment: You scale using `(pViewRange-closest)/pViewRange`. Maybe this is desired, but in real life it's something like `ScreenY/closest` (so the object never gets to 0). While this improves the results, there is still some distortion left.

Comment: @Luke100000 that has fixed the distorsion of walls seeming to bend away from the player ex. looking at and walking past a wall perpendicular to your movement would make the wall seem as if it's bending away from you. But there is another form of distortion - any objects visual distance will be increased even more if it is already close to the camera and decreased even more than it should be if it is far, proportionally to the difference between the current scanX angle and pRot angle. ie things to the sides of the screen get distorted.

Comment: I have just realised this is because of the fisheye correction effect, if I remove the cosine multiplication then there are no more types of distortions except the fisheye effect, but it looks as if i dit the math correctly on that one, It is responsible for the edge distortion but without it the fisheye effect appears.